# Good shared hosting for sending newsletter?

Tags: hosting

I am running a phplist on Joyent (TextDrive).
They announced that they sold that service to another company.
As I am not sure about the new company, I need to move my account to some other hosting company.

Can you recommend a shared hosting company that I can use?
I need to send newsletter to subscribers (they are not spams. about 500 members).
Most shared hosting servers have limit in sending mail (100 per hour or so).

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 4):

You might look into [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) if your hosting needs are limited to sending e-mail newsletters.  They have a plan for $10/mo for up to 500 subscribers (next level up from that is $30/mo).  They've been around for a long time and are very reputable and maintain relationships with ISPs and major e-mail providers to help your messages get delivered better than most people can from a leased virtual server or shared hosting account.

Comment: Another vote for MailChimp. Their servers and IP space are optimized to get your messages to the remote mailbox. You could also use something like ConstantContact. 

Shared hosting is meant for webpages (and maybe email) and is not really geared towards sending out many messages.

Comment: I voted up your answer.  I'm a very satisfied customer of MailChimp.